# Allure report is showing empty contents after Jenkins job execution

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

I have a Jenkins job "FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION", that is to execute some selenium test cases in docker, and the one of the post job work is to generate the allure report. But somehow, **the report is always of 0 results !**

Following picture is my job configuration.

[image]

As you may find in which, I have this command to have the test cases executed in docker.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm -v ${ROOT}/allure-reports:/allure-reports fext_extender behave ...
```

Since the output files of ownership **"root"**, I have the 2nd command to workaround to change the whole /allure-reports ownership.

```
docker run --rm -i --entrypoint /bin/sh -e HOST_UID=`id -u` -v ${ROOT}/allure-reports:/allure-reports alpine:latest -c 'chown -R ${HOST_UID}:${HOST_UID} /allure-reports/'
```

from the console of one job execution,  I can see everything was carried over smoothly, and allure report is **generated**.

```
...
1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
8 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 1m2.060s
+ id -u
+ docker run --rm -i --entrypoint /bin/sh -e HOST_UID=111 -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-reports:/allure-reports alpine:latest -c chown -R ${HOST_UID}:${HOST_UID} /allure-reports/
+ set -e
[FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION] $ /usr/share/allure/bin/allure generate /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-reports -c -o /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-report
Report successfully generated to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But somehow, if I click the allure link, I can only see a 0-testcase results.

From the platform where the Jenkins tasks are being hold, I can see these 2 extra files created under "allure-reports" when allure generate command is called.

```
jenkins@Jenkins-CJI:~/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-reports$ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-reports
jenkins@Jenkins-CJI:~/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-reports$ whoami
jenkins
jenkins@Jenkins-CJI:~/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION/allure-reports$ ls -ltr | tail -5
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins messagebus  78515 Nov 18 15:29 Screenshot_2021-11-18T18:29:25.491659_1637278165.4916792.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins messagebus 134025 Nov 18 15:29 Screenshot_2021-11-18T18:29:26.011988_1637278166.0120175.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins messagebus 134025 Nov 18 15:29 Screenshot_2021-11-18T18:29:26.384782_1637278166.3848066.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins messagebus     78 Nov 18 15:29 testrun.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins messagebus    295 Nov 18 15:29 executor.json
```

And here is the allure-report looks like:

```
jenkins@Jenkins-CJI:~/workspace/FEXT_21.4_AUTOMATION$ tree -L 2 allure-report
allure-report
├── app.js
├── data
│   ├── attachments
│   ├── behaviors.csv
│   ├── behaviors.json
│   ├── categories.csv
│   ├── categories.json
│   ├── packages.json
│   ├── suites.csv
│   ├── suites.json
│   ├── test-cases
│   └── timeline.json
├── export
│   ├── influxDbData.txt
│   ├── mail.html
│   └── prometheusData.txt
├── favicon.ico
├── history
│   ├── categories-trend.json
│   ├── duration-trend.json
│   ├── history.json
│   ├── history-trend.json
│   └── retry-trend.json
├── index.html
├── plugins
│   ├── behaviors
│   ├── junit
│   ├── packages
│   ├── screen-diff
│   ├── trx
│   ├── xctest
│   └── xunit-xml
├── styles.css
└── widgets
    ├── behaviors.json
    ├── categories.json
    ├── categories-trend.json
    ├── duration.json
    ├── duration-trend.json
    ├── environment.json
    ├── executors.json
    ├── history-trend.json
    ├── launch.json
    ├── retry-trend.json
    ├── severity.json
    ├── status-chart.json
    ├── suites.json
    └── summary.json
```

Does anyone know why allure report is empty ?

Thanks for the help.

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `${ROOT}` use `${WORKSPACE}`.
WORKSPACE is a Jenkins variable that contains the WORKSPACE PATH

`-v ${WORKSPACE}/allure-reports:/allure-reports`

Also, check after running the job if there are some alure results files in the `/allure-results` directory inside the Jenkins workspace here:

[image]

If you don't see any results files in the workspace, it's because you are not mounting the right internal directory in the container, in this case `/allure-reports` (inside the container)

Comment: I have just used default "${WORKSPACE}" value to have my job re-executed . But since the default ${WORKSPACE} and my customized "${ROOT}" is pointing to the same location, I don't see difference in regarding the final report.  In either case, after my selenium docker is being executed, I have seen a list of PNG files created under /allure-reports dir, and after the allure generate is executed, I have seen these 2 extra json files generated under that dir:  "executor.json" and "testrun.json".

Comment: Thanks for the help.  1) I didn't know there is a ${WORKSPACE}, by default, is pointing to the root of this Jenkins Job. So just have it replaced and gave a try. But since my customized  ${ROOT} value and ${WORKSPACE} are both pointing the same location, the running results is the same as my previous setting.  2) After my execution, I have seen a list of png files created under ${WorkSpace}/all-reports/.., but I don't have this "allure-results" dir, 3) On my Jenkins service, which is setup on a UBUNTU box couple years ago,  I don't see this "Workspace" link ?

Comment: Check your framework where is putting those results files, the best way is to use your relative (project root) and put the folder allure-results in there. The Workspace link appears when you enter your job. If it's a pipeline job, then you have to enter to the build number and in there you will see the workspace link

Answer (score 0):

These are my final commands in junkins job to create success allure reports.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm -v ${WORKSPACE}/allure-reports:/allure-reports fext_extender behave -verbose -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o /allure-reports <feature_files>

docker run --rm -i --entrypoint /bin/sh -e HOST_UID=`id -u` -v ${WORKSPACE}/allure-reports:/allure-reports alpine:latest -c 'chown -R ${HOST_UID}:${HOST_UID} /allure-reports/'
```

Comments:

- As Frank mentioned here, https://gitter.im/allure-docker-service/community?at=5f2987858d82e662520511be, need to mount a volume, something as if
  "${WORKSPACE}/allure-reports:/allure-reports".
- the ownership of the docker execution output files is "root", need to find a way to have the ${WORKSPACE}/allure-reports ownership changed to be "Jenkins". Otherwise, the follow-up allure generate run will be failed, as no permission inside /allure-reports.
- In my first command, I was using "... -o ./allure-reports", which is not the same location as "... -o /allure-reports".  And because of that, the list of "...-result.json" files were not generated after 1st command execution!

After I have these 3 area corrected, I have my Jenkins results in the end.

Comment: For the second point, you have to pass the jenkins user as parameter. You can get the jenkins user executing `echo "$(id -u):$(id -g)"` . If you want to pass the user you can do it in this way `docker-compose run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" ...`

Comment: That would be nice and clean. But I have just had it tried in such steps: have the whole /allure-reports directory deleted => had the new command tried with the extra user option, and it fails.   What happen is, a new /allure-reports is created , of which owner still "root", and my command is trying to dump the PNG files of owner "Jenkins" into it. and permission denied.  What I don't understand is, why the /allure-reports still of the "root" ?

Comment: I recommend you not to delete the `allure-results` directory, just remove the content of that directory. In that way, only you will create files with the jenkins user. You can select the directory path of the `/allure-reports` directory inside your container with the option `--report-path` (if you are using allure command line)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have tried  as you suggested and everything was done in one command. Nice and Clean. Thanks for the help.